# Is every set equinumerous to a well founded set in acyclic ZF?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

If we replace the axiom of Regularity in $\sf ZF$ by the scheme of Acyclicity, which is:

$$\begin{align} n=2,3,\dots;\ &  \neg \exists x_1,\dots , \exists x_n: \\ &x_1 \in  x_2 \land \dots \land x_{n-1} \in x_n \ \land \\ &x_1=x_n \end{align}$$

Call this Acyclic ZF.

> Does Corets' principle of every set is equinumerouse to some well-founded set, hold in Acyclic ZF.

Comment: I guess a variation of Mostowski's ordered model gives a counterexample, but I have not checked things in detail. [I sketched a construction of the model on my website post.](https://hanuljeon95.github.io/Infinite-decreasing-in-chain-and-countable-choice/)